# jQueryUI Autocomplete doesn't show up when appending words to previous words

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

In my project, I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin to the TextField. I have written the following code which is working fine:

```
<textarea id="result" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

---

```
$('#result').autocomplete({
    source: sugData
});
```

Now I am explaining the problem briefly:

If there are some words like :

```
 I go to school
 I am a boy
 I play cricket
```

Then when I type `I` in textfield, the server will respond with `go, am, play` which will be stored in `sugData` variable. Now when I start typing `go` just after `I`(appending), the autocomplete suggestion doesn't show any suggestions to fill. I know this is happening because `I go` is not equal to any data available in the array stored in `sugData` i.e `go, am, play`.

Anyway to solve this issue?

**PS**: I am sending the complete text in the textfield to the server side which is necessary.

**EDIT**: If I just consider the last word to sent to server, then the server will respond with `I` instead of `go, am, play`. So, it is not possible to trim just the last word.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an static object, give the source property a function taking as arguments the request and the response function.

- Work with request.term to get the source word.
- Filter yourself your sugData and use the result as the argument of the response function invocation.

For more information on source being implemented as a function, please visit jquery ui documentation about it.